# Is SharePoint 2010 supported on SQL server 2012 SP2

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is SharePoint 2010 supported on SQL server 2012 SP2?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a short answer: **Yes**, It's supported,

> In order to use **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP2**, you must use
>   **SharePoint 2010 SP1** or later of SharePoint Server 2010!

---

**Note:**

> In order to maintain SharePoint and SQL Server compatibility Microsoft
>   use the `“SharePoint N-1 on SQL Server N+1”`  equation to determine
>   version support. Using SharePoint Server 2010 as an example, the N
>   release of SQL Server is 2008/2008 R2 and N+1 is SQL Server 2012.

- The **N** in the above example refers to the SQL Server version, **not the updates or service packs.**

Based on the above N equation, the SharePoint 2010 SP 1 is supported on SQL Server 2012, so it also supported on SQL Server 2012 SP1 and SP2 ...etc

- Also, What is mentioned in [Hardware and software requirements SharePoint Server 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.14).aspx) is the minimum requirements for Database Server.

[image]

For more details check [SQL Server Supported for SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/02/27/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/)

Comment: Thanks for your post -  I read the article but it only mentions the base version SQL Server 2010 and not the service packs - I don't think this makes it certain that its supported

Comment: @Craig Please check my update, Hope it clear now!

Comment: @Craig Please mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you , thanks!

Comment: I will - we plan on install tonight and will have this verified shortly thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help we upgraded the server last night and it works normally